# A B-topological ring that is not semi-topological?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

> A topological space $A$ that is also a ring with operations '+' and '.'   where  $ A\times A$  carries product topology, is a semi-topological ring if the mappings $$a_1: A\times A \to A\ \text{such that}\ (x,y)\to x+y$$ , $$a_2: A \to A\ \text{such that}\ x\to -x$$ and $$a_3: A \to A\ \text{such that}\ (x,y) \to x.y$$ are semi-continuous.

> A topological space $A$ that is also a ring with operations '+' and '.'   where  $ A\times A$  carries product topology, is a B-topological ring if the mappings $$a_1: A\times A \to A\ \text{such that}\ (x,y)\to x+y$$ , $$a_2: A \to A\ \text{such that}\ x\to -x$$ and $$a_3: A \to A\ \text{such that}\ (x,y) \to x.y$$ are b-continuous.

where,

> A function $f:X \to Y$ from topological space $X$ to topological space $Y$ is said to be b-continuous (semi continuous) if for each $x\in X$ and
> each open set $U \subset Y$ containing $f(x)$ there exists a b-open (semi-open) set $V \subset X$ containing $x$ such that $f(V) \subset U$.

> A set $B$ is called b-open if $B \subset Int(cl(B)) \cup cl(Int(B))$ and $S$ is semi open if $S \subset cl(Int(S))$

Clearly, Topological rings $\implies$ semi-topological rings $\implies$ B-topological rings but not conversely.

After all these definitions I seek a B-topological ring that is not semi-topological. I already have other counterexamples but this one I have no idea about.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you already have an example of a B-continuous map between some $X$ and $Y$ (without additional ring structure) that is not semi-continuous?

Comment: @Vincent No. I have asked that too. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478794/b-continuous-but-not-semi-continuous

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to adapt Sebastian Spindler's answer to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478794/b-continuous-but-not-semi-continuous) to this one.  Informally, redefine multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ so that the product of any two irrational numbers is $0$, but otherwise multiplication is the same.
Formally, let $\{1\}\sqcup T$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.  Let $X$ be a set of indeterminates equinumerous with $T$ and $S=\mathbb{Q}[X]$.  Finally, choose $R=S/(ab:a,b\in X)$; then the bijection between $T$ and $X$ extends by linearity to an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces between $R$ and $(1\sqcup T)\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$.  Give $R$ the topology induced by this bijection, and then abuse notation by identifying $T$ and $X$.

Then $({\times}_R)^{-1}((1,2))\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}T)^2$, which has empty interior.  But $R$ is $B$-topological, for:

- If $0\in U$, then $({\times}_R)^{-1}(U)\supseteq(\mathbb{Q}T)^2$, which is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
- Otherwise, $({\times}_R)^{-1}(U)=(\times_{\mathbb{R}})^{-1}(U)\cap(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}T)^2)$, which is dense in $(\times_{\mathbb{R}})^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: This is not a ring: We have $1 \times_R \sqrt{2} = 0 = 1 \times_R (2 - \sqrt{2})$, but $2 = 1 \times_R 2 = 1 \times_R (\sqrt{2} + 2 - \sqrt{2})$, so this multiplication does not distribute over the usual addition on $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @SebastianSpindler: Yes, I thought I could get away without using linear algebra and was wrong.  I've corrected the answer now.

Comment: I don't think the formulas for the preimages are correct: E.g. if $\sqrt{2} \in T$, then $(\tfrac{3}{4} \cdot \sqrt{2}) \times_R \sqrt{2} = \tfrac{3}{2} \in (1,2)$, but $(\tfrac{3}{4} \cdot \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) \in (\mathbb{Q}T)^2.$ Moreover, the formula in the case $0 \in U$ can never be correct since $(\times_R)^{-1}(U)$ is a subset of $R \times R.$

Comment: @SebastianSpindler: I had two errors: $R\to R^2$ and $(ab:a\neq b\in T)\to(ab:a,b\in T)$.  Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: The second correction introduces a new issue: The ideal $(ab \mid a,b \in T)$ might be the whole ring $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ (e.g. if $\sqrt{2} \in T$), which gives the topological ring $R = \{0\}.$

Comment: @SebastianSpindler: No, because what I mean by $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ is the free (associative, unital, commutative) $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra generated by an indeterminate for each element of $T$; for example $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is the ring of polynomials in an indeterminate called (confusingly) "$\sqrt{2}$" and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$ (for example).  I've rewritten the solution to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But why is the preimage of any open $U$ with $0 \in U$ all of $R \times R$? Don't we have $1 \times_R 2 = 2 \notin (-1,1)$, so $(1,2) \notin (\times_R)^{-1}(U)$ for example? Instead we only know that the preimage is dense, which is sufficient for what we want to show.

Comment: @SebastianSpindler: Ah, yeah.  Thanks

Comment: That preimage still does not look quite right, e.g. $(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 = 1 + 2 \sqrt{2}$ does not lie in $U = (-1,1)$, but the pair $(1 + \sqrt{2}, 1 + \sqrt{2})$ also does not lie in $(\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\})^2.$ The only thing we can say for certain is that $(\times_R)^{-1}(U)$ contains $(\mathbb{Q}T)^2$ (it will be a bit bigger since $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$), but this already implies that the preimage is dense in $R^2.$

Comment: @SebastianSpindler: OK.