# b-continuous but not semi-continuous?

Tags: general-topology

> A function $f:X \to Y$ from topological space $X$ to topological space $Y$ is said to be b-continuous (semi-continuous) if for each $x\in X$ and
> each open set $U \subset Y$ containing $f(x)$ there exists a b-open set (semi-open) $V \subset X$ containing $x$ such that $f(V) \subset U$.

> A set $B$ is called b-open if $B \subset Int(cl(B)) \cup cl(Int(B))$ and $S$ is semi open if $S \subset cl(Int(S))$

I need a function that is b-continuous which is not semi-continuous? My attempts have been futile.

**My trivial attempt-**
I think the map $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ where $\mathbb{Q}$ has usual topology and $Y=\mathbb{Q}$ has indiscrete topology such that $\phi$ goes to $\phi$ and all the rational numbers go to $\mathbb{Q}$.
Will it work?

Comment: Hint: A dense subset with dense complement is b-open but not semi-open.

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld Well yes I know that rationals are b-open and not semi open, what I need is a function from X to Y where both X and Y are $\mathbb{R}$ and inverse image of any open set is......?

Comment: Where did you state $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb R$ in the question? Maybe say exactly what you want to have answered in the original post.

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld i don't want it to be R,  I was just implying if I take R would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $$f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \, x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1, & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the Euclidean topology. For any subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ the preimage $$f^{-1}(U) \in \{\emptyset, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}\}$$
then is b-open since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is b-continuous.

However, $f$ is not semi-continuous: The interval $U = (-\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open with $f(0) = 0 \in U$, but for any semi-open $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $f(V) \subseteq U$ we have $$V \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{Int}(V)) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}(U))) = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb{Q})) = \operatorname{cl}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$$
and thus $0 \notin V.$

Regarding your trivial attempt: Any function mapping to a target space equipped with the indiscrete topology is continuous and hence also b-continuous and semi-continuous.

Comment: Thank you.......